# Only a portion of image converted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are resizing the image and we are facing a issue.Only portion of image is getting resized and we are using below code.

```
public Bitmap ScaleImage(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
            var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
            var ratio = 1.0;
            if (maxWidth == 0)
            {
                ratio = ratioY;
            }
            else if (maxHeight == 0)
            {
                ratio = ratioX;
            }
            else
            {
                ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
            }


            var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
            var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);
            Graphics graphicsObj;
            var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            //var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            graphicsObj = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
            graphicsObj.Clear(Color.White);
            Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            return newImage;
        }
```

Please follow this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7YetfEWCrj2U1ZFMmt1cy1oYVk/view?usp=sharing)  for example.

Comment: Can you share the source image file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7YetfEWCrj2c2ZCdXFSbGhkSWs/view?usp=sharing 
Some time it is converting and some time not.

Comment: interesting. the reason why I asked for the image was that I tried a couple of image with different formats, and they all seem to have rendered fine. 

One more thing though. This image you're returning here, are you writing it to disk or sending it over the network. Just making sure we aren't dealing with an intermediately loading image hung up whilst rendering here.

Comment: This Code is the part of ApiController which is fetching images from hard drive and returning those images to webpage. Thank you sir for your efforts :)

Comment: interesting. So are you getting this partial image rendering on your own machine or a remote one? If remote look out for if the request has been disconnected from the server or has timed out.